# Confusing join - full table, joined with corresponding records in another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm having a bit of an issue try to get the result set I want. Basically I have these two tables:

```
phonemanager_defaults

| id  | tag             | number        |
|-----|-----------------|---------------|
| 1   | MAIN            | 0800 111 1111 |
| 2   | LANDLINE        | 0800 222 2222 |
| 3   | CUSTOMERSERVICE | 0800 333 3333 |

phonemanager_cookie

| number_id  | cookie      | number        |
|------------|-------------|---------------|
| 1          | twitter     | 0800 444 4444 |
| 2          | twitter     | 0800 555 5555 |
| 1          | facebook    | 0800 666 6666 |
| 2          | facebook    | 0800 777 7777 |
| 3          | facebook    | 0800 888 8888 |
| 1          | ppc         | 0800 999 9999 |
```

I'm creating a function in PHP such that I pass in a `cookie` as a parameter and I want to return all of `phonemanager_defaults` joined up with any corresponding records from `phonemanager_cookie` of course joined on the `id` and `number_id` columns and filtered down by the `cookie` I specify.

Take for example if I specify `twitter` as the `cookie`, this is the result set I would expect:

```
Result set (twitter)

| id  | tag             | default_number | cookie  | cookie_number |
|-----|-----------------|----------------|---------|---------------|
| 1   | MAIN            | 0800 111 1111  | twitter | 0800 444 4444 |
| 2   | LANDLINE        | 0800 222 2222  | twitter | 0800 555 5555 |
| 3   | CUSTOMERSERVICE | 0800 333 3333  | NULL    | NULL          |
```

If I specify `ppc` as the `cookie`:

```
Result set (ppc)

| id  | tag             | default_number | cookie  | cookie_number |
|-----|-----------------|----------------|---------|---------------|
| 1   | MAIN            | 0800 111 1111  | ppc     | 0800 999 9999 |
| 2   | LANDLINE        | 0800 222 2222  | NULL    | NULL          |
| 3   | CUSTOMERSERVICE | 0800 333 3333  | NULL    | NULL          |
```

I've tried many a different query but can't seem to get it right. I would have thought a `LEFT JOIN` would have worked but it just doesn't return all the records from `phonemanager_defaults`.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
SELECT 
    `phonemanager_defaults`.`id` AS `id`,
    `phonemanager_defaults`.`tag` AS `tag`,
    `phonemanager_defaults`.`number` AS `default_number`,
    `phonemanager_cookie`.`cookie` AS `cookie`,
    `phonemanager_cookie`.`number` AS `cookie_number`
FROM
    `phonemanager_defaults`
        LEFT JOIN
    `phonemanager_cookie` ON `phonemanager_defaults`.`id` = `phonemanager_cookie`.`number_id`
WHERE
    `phonemanager_cookie`.`cookie` = 'twitter';
```

Would anyone be able to suggest a query that would give me what I want? SQL isn't my strong point.

Comment: An SQL Fiddle would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all the results from `phonemanager_defaults` move your condition from where to ON clause of join `WHERE` filter will be applied on whole result set while using additional condition in join will join the needed results from `phonemanager_cookie` and for non matched rows will give you the null

```
SELECT 
    `phonemanager_defaults`.`id` AS `id`,
    `phonemanager_defaults`.`tag` AS `tag`,
    `phonemanager_defaults`.`number` AS `default_number`,
    `phonemanager_cookie`.`cookie` AS `cookie`,
    `phonemanager_cookie`.`number` AS `cookie_number`
FROM
    `phonemanager_defaults`
        LEFT JOIN
    `phonemanager_cookie` ON `phonemanager_defaults`.`id` = `phonemanager_cookie`.`number_id` 
AND `phonemanager_cookie`.`cookie` = 'twitter'
```

Comment: I have to wait another 5 minutes but I will accept your answer.